# react scope value There is no equal value in the range

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
update = (key, value) => {
const newState = {};
newState[key] = value;

this.setState({ newState });
// firstName : hahaha
//    <HelMag msg={this.state.firstName}> </HelMag>
// The value of the browser must be changed.
// But the value(this.newState => hahaha) does not change.

console.log(newState);
  };
```

firstName : hahaha

```
< HelMag msg={this.state.firstName}> </HelMag>
```

The value of the browser must be changed.
   But the value(this.newState => hahaha) does not change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r57rv9qkko

The full code does not rise, so replace it with a link
Please excuse me.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your syntax here:

```
this.setState({ newState });
```

This should be changed to:

```
this.setState(newState)
```

When wrapping a named variable (such as newState) in brackets, you're creating a new object with a property / value corresponding to your variable name. In the case of your example here, `{newState}` is equivalent to: `{ newState: { [key]: value } }`. If you inspected your state after calling `setState` you'd see that it now has a property called `newState`. So instead of passing an object containing the value you want to add to your state, you should pass an object containing the key / value pairs you want to change, e.g. `this.setState({ [key]: value })`

Comment: Thank you very much.
I lost three days because of this.